# Is there a way to reset Cloud Firestore's database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently in testing mode, and I keep changing my structure. The problem is that every time I want to try something new I need to manually delete each collection by typing it's name, which takes forever.
Also, I know that deleting a collection deletes its documents, but deleting a documents doesn't delete its subcollections.
I have a few documents with suncollections and when I delete them, i don't see the subcollections anymore? Where are they? Are they lost in some database vortex taking space on my allocated disk forever now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a document but not its subcollections, the subcollections still exist and you access them exactly like you would normally.  The document ID will appear in the console in italics to indicate that there's no document present, but there are subcollections organized under the ID.

There is currently no way to wipe out a Firestore database, other then to delete all the document using the normal ways that you would do so.  Delete them in the console, or delete them by querying for them, iterating the results, and deleting each document.

Comment: Thank you Doug, you helped me a lot in the last 24 hours with Firestore answers I really appreciate it.
Regarding the deleted documents. I have deleted yesterday all my top level collections from the console. I know for certain the had subcollections (I have been using the Shards for like counts). In my console though I see absolutely no trace of anything. Completely blank. If I didn't know that subcollections don't delete automatically, I would have thought that that's what happened because they're no where to be found, and I can't remember their paths. Am I missing something?

Comment: It might be the case that programmatically deleting all the documents in a collection causes the collection to completely vanish in the console, hiding each nested subcollection (which are still present and accessible in code).  Try manually creating a document in the top-level collection to see if the subcollections appear again.

Comment: I see. Honestly I don't remember them When I'm done with the testing I'll be creating a new account as I am using my personal email for this one, but maybe it's worth having it more accessible as I can imagine it leads to forever-lost data on your servers. I for example would never use it and can't delete it. Just my 2 cents.
Thanks!